# Pandas DataFrame column corrupted while calculating an addition column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset with the following columns and rows

```
Scored Probabilities for Class "1"  Scored Probabilities for Class "2"  Scored Probabilities for Class "3"  Scored Labels
0.258471                0.009299                0.005433                1
0.154108                0.009577                0.527308                3
0.001949                0.634572                0.000953                2
```

(Actually, there are 17 "Classes", but I've simplified to 3 for this post)

I'd like to add an extra column called "Scored Label Probability" which is the max of the first three columns (actually, the max of all columns that are called "Scored Probabilities for Class "X""). So the result should look like this:-

```
                                        Scored Label Probability (new)
0.258471    0.009299    0.005433    1   0.258471
0.154108    0.009577    0.527308    3   0.527308
0.001949    0.634572    0.000953    2   0.634572
```

Here is my code (below). Unfortunately the "Scored Labels" column (the 4th column in the example data) is getting corrupted (replaced by a different integer numeric). 
Any suggestions on how to fix it?
Thanks

```
# The script MUST contain a function named azureml_main
# which is the entry point for this module.

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# The entry point function can contain up to two input arguments:
#   Param<dataframe1>: a pandas.DataFrame
#   Param<dataframe2>: a pandas.DataFrame
def azureml_main(df = None, df2 = None):

    # First add the empty column
    df['Scored Label Probability'] = 0.0

    for rowindex, row in df.iterrows():
        max_probability =0.0
        column_value = 0.0
        column_name = ''
        for column_name, column_value in row.iteritems():
            if column_name.startswith('Scored Probabilities for Class'):
                if column_value>max_probability:
                    max_probability = column_value

        # print (max_probability,max_prob_column_name)
        df.set_value(rowindex,'Scored Label Probability',max_probability)

    # Return value must be of a sequence of pandas.DataFrame
    return df
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make use of [`DF.max`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.max.html) method along `axis=1`(columns) which gives you the highest value across all the columns which start with the matching string (found using [`DF.filter`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html) method):

```
df.filter(like='Scored Probabilities for Class').max(axis=1)

0    0.258471
1    0.527308
2    0.634572
dtype: float64
```

---

Inorder to do the same using `R`, you can use the `pmax` function which returns the parallel maxima of the columns that start with the specified prefix.

Additionally using the `dplyr` package, we could allow `select` to subset and with the aid of string helpers like `starts_with` to do the above `filter` equivalent operation.

```
library(dplyr)
df$max <- do.call(pmax, select(df, starts_with('Scored Probabilities for Class')))
```

Comment: Nice! I'll try it.

Comment: Actually, I may need to re-write this in R. Any idea how you write the same thing in R?